# PostgreSQL: How can I replace to one column from the json values of another column?

Tags: regex, postgresql, jsonb

I wasn't able to find a solution to this one.

Say I have a table like this

```
with tmp_table(json_row, message) as (
    values 
    ('{"key1": 1, "key2":"first"}'::jsonb, 'this ${key2} is a test of ${key1}'),
    ('{"key1": 2, "key2":"second"}', 'this ${key2} is a test'),
    ('{"key1": 3, "key2":"third"}', 'this ${key1} is a test of ${key2}')
)
select * from tmp_table
```

[image]

How can I replace the external parameters from the json values of the other column so that the expected result is

[image]

Thanks in advance!

Edit: I want this to be with regex-replace to find whatever is between the `${}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can combine the `regexp_matches` and `regexp_split_to_table` [pattern matching functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-matching.html) to create a table of string parts from each message - each row consisting of a literal part and a `${…}`-replacement part, the last row not containing a replacement variable. Then do the replacement by choosing the respective key from the json object, then [`string_agg`regate](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-aggregate.html) all the parts back together into the result. Do this with a subquery for each row in your table:

```
SELECT (
  SELECT string_agg(concat(literal, data->>variable[1]), '')
  FROM (
    SELECT
      regexp_split_to_table(message, '\$\{([^}]*)\}') AS literal,
      regexp_matches(message, '\$\{([^}]*)\}', 'g') AS variable
  ) AS parts
) AS result
FROM example
```

<sup>([online demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/97hK5YYE))</sup>

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
with tmp_table(json_row, message) as (
    values 
    ('{"key1": 1, "key2":"first"}'::jsonb, 'this ${key2} is a test of ${key1}'),
    ('{"key1": 2, "key2":"second"}'::jsonb, 'this ${key2} is a test'),
    ('{"key1": 3, "key2":"third"}'::jsonb, 'this ${key1} is a test of ${key2}')
)
select json_row,replace(replace(message,'${key1}', json_row->>'key1'),'${key2}', json_row->>'key2') as message from tmp_table
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/ZiNBx0I1)

the output
[image]

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. Forgot to mention that I don't want this to be hardcoded. I don't know in advance that the external parameters are called key1 and key2. Essentially I want with regex replace to find whatever is between ${} and make the replacement